# click effect in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, macbook, mouse-click

I want some feedback when I do a single/double click on my mouse. Is there a way I can get this feedback, perhaps like a ripple/wave pool on the screen ?

I use Mac OS X.

Comment: As no-one answered yet, I guess I'm not the only one who does not understand what you mean. Can you explain what you're expecting to happen when clicking? Note the "edit" link underneath your post. (And while you're editing your question: [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) and [Mac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) are not the same; your question is about a Mac computer, not a MAC address. Or, even more accurately, I guess your question is about OS X, not about the Macintosh hardware?)

Comment: @arjan- sorry i expect that when i click it may be single or double some effects like wave from clicked spot will be happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have you tried [OmniDazzle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle/)?

Comment: this what i expect thanx

Answer (score 0):

[Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com/) can give you a small visible spot each time you click.